# How to prevent user from downloading Video files From Application in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, download, package

I would be working on an application, which is a learning app and want to prevent students from downloading the videos from the app, Is there any package or any way to prevent this.

Comment: could you please add the code you have done so far?

Comment: can we use `permission_handler` (https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package for this ?